# Как определить тип устройства?

Tags: c#, uwp

Надо чтобы приложение переходило в полноэкранный режим только на телефонах.
Пробовал только так.

```
ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Но, логично, так в полный экран будет переходить и при запуске на PC и на телефоне. А отслеживать размер экрана на котором запускается приложение, как по мне - криво... Может есть какой нибудь более простой способ указать, что на телефонах должен быть полный экран?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить тип устройства, на котором запущено приложение, можно так:

```
var platform = Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
if (platform == "Windows.Mobile")
{
    ...
}
```

Другие возможные значения:

- Windows.Desktop (если `UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Mouse`, то десктоп, иначе планшет)
- Windows.Universal (это IoT устройство)
- Windows.Team (это surface hub)

Правда Microsoft [не рекомендует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.devicefamily.aspx) использовать это свойство. Официальная политика такова, что вам не должно хотеться кастомизировать приложение в зависимости от платформы.